# How to modify raku code "say $?PACKAGE;" to print the fully qualified package name

Tags: scope, package, raku

```
    say $?PACKAGE;
    class Foo {
        say $?PACKAGE;
        class Bar {
            say $?PACKAGE;
            my package P {say $?PACKAGE;}
        }
    }
```

This code prints:

```
(GLOBAL)
(Foo)
(Bar)
(P)
```

Wanted:

```
(GLOBAL)
(GLOBAL::Foo)
(GLOBAL::Foo::Bar)
(GLOBAL::Foo::Bar::P)
```

Comment: `say $?PACKAGE.raku`

Answer (score 5):

For the benefit of others who may have the same question, I'll expand on the correct answer you already got in a comment from @ugexe:

You can get print the full package path by printing the debug representation of `$*PACKAGE` with the [.raku](https://docs.raku.org/type/Mu#method_raku) method or (on Rakudo only), with the [dd](https://docs.raku.org/programs/01-debugging#Dumper_function_(dd)) routine.

Thus, your code could be modified to have the output shown below:

```
dd $?PACKAGE;                         # OUTPUT: «GLOBAL»
class Foo {
    dd $?PACKAGE;                     # OUTPUT: «Foo»
    class Bar {
        dd $?PACKAGE;                 # OUTPUT: «Foo::Bar»
        my package P {say $?PACKAGE;} # OUTPUT: «Foo::Bar::P»
    }
}
```

Note that `GLOBAL` is implicit and thus isn't printed unless it is the only item in the path.

Comment: "You can get the full package path by printing the debug representation of `$*PACKAGE` with the `.raku` method...". I get that `.raku` can be helpful in debugging but I want to make clear to readers that the intent of `.raku` is not related to debugging but is instead that it displays a Raku source code fragment that, when fed back into a compiler, will produce the value of its invocant. It fails at that for some values, but those failures are (at least imo) bugs (albeit some of them being quite difficult to deal with, eg circular data structures that are constructed by multiple statements).

Answer (score 4):

When you call `say` you get `.gist` of the argument.
The `.gist` is intended to give a human just enough information to figure out what is going on.

If you actually want the name of the package, ask for it.
Or more specifically, ask the metamodel to give it to you with `.^name`.

```raku
say $?PACKAGE.^name;       # GLOBAL
class Foo {
  say $?PACKAGE.^name;     # Foo
  class Bar {
    say $?PACKAGE.^name;   # Foo::Bar
    my package P {
      say $?PACKAGE.^name; # Foo::Bar::P
    }
  }
}
```